# How to use Oracle CTE for such query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I have a query that looks like following:

```
SELECT m.Name, (m.Value + NVL(a1.Value1, 0) + NVL(a2.Value2,0) + NVL(a3.Value3,0) "Value"
FROM m MainTable
LEFT JOIN Additional1 a1 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN Additional2 a2 ON (...)
LEFT JOIN Additional3 a3 ON (...)
WHERE (conditions on m)
ORDER BY 1;
```

These query produces **multiple** rows for each `Name`.

I need to limit it to **one** row for each `Name` with the following logic:  include the row which Value is the closest to the average Value for a given Name.

Something tells me that **CTE** should allow for a more compact code and hopefully more effective implementation, so I do not need to repeat the virtually same query several times.

Can you please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A CTE can help, but I think the key are the analytic functions.  First, you can calculate the average of value for each name using an analytic function.  Then you can rank the absolute value of the differences.

Here is the version with the CTE:

```
with t as (
    SELECT m.Name,
           (m.Value + NVL(a1.Value1, 0) + NVL(a2.Value2,0) + NVL(a3.Value3,0) "Value"
    FROM m MainTable
         LEFT JOIN Additional1 a1 ON (...)
         LEFT JOIN Additional2 a2 ON (...)
         LEFT JOIN Additional3 a3 ON (...)
   WHERE (conditions on m)
)
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by avgdiff) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   abs(value - avg(value) over (partition by name)) as AvgDiff
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Why is the "outside" query and both internal queries all have **the same** alias?